# Doubt about a theorem on Direct Sums.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Theorem: The necessary and sufficient condition for a vector space $V(F)$ to be a direct sum of its two subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$ are that
>
> 1. $V=W_1+W_2$
> 2. $W_1\cap W_2=\{0\}$

As far as I understand a subspace must always contain $0$ and therefore the second condition should always hold. Then why has the author mentioned it in the Theorem? Please explain.

Comment: The case where $W_1\cap W_2={\rm span} (v),\ v\neq 0$ is possible so that we need the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That any subspace contains $0$ implies that $\{0\}\subset W_1\cap W_2$, but in general this need not be an equality. For example, the intersection of two planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a line, not the origin, so $\mathbb{R}^3$ cannot be the direct sum of two planes.

Comment: Very helpful answer! Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

The point of the direct sum is that each vector has a unique decomposition. The intersection should thus be no bigger than $\{0\}$: suppose you had a nonzero vector $u \in W_1 \cap W_2$. Then if $v=w_1+w_2$, $w_i \in W_i$ is a decomposition of $v$, so is $ v = (w_1-u)+(w_2+u) $ and the decomposition is thus not unique.